# How to loop through a folder and add the names of all the files into cells in a column in Libreoffice? Using .csv and Anki

Tags: csv, mp3, libreoffice, anki

I have several folders, each containing several thousand .mp3 files of example sentences spoken by native speakers. I want to loop through the folder in order and add all the names of the files to the first column of a LibreOffice spreadsheet, so in each cell in the column it looks like [sound:name_of_file.mp3]. The names of the file are in order, but they are split up by section and chapter, so it would be easier if there was a way to grab the name of the file and use that, as opposed to coming up with a function that changes the text based on a for loop or something like that.

I want to create a .csv file including all the [sound:name_of_file.mp3] text, that I will upload into Anki as a deck, and then just copy all the .mp3 files from each of the original folders into Anki's media folder so the card references the audio and plays it.

Is there a way to do this, and if so, how would it be done?

Thank you!

Comment: It is very easy to enumerate all the files in the specified folder and collect filenames in cells; for this purpose, the [**ReadDirectories()**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/262333/get-a-list-of-file-names-from-a-folder-and-all-subfolders/) function is in the standard library Tools in the UCB module. It is also easy to quickly write the accumulated information into a CSV file - in the same Tools library there is a **SaveDataToFile()** procedure. But it is completely incomprehensible what you mean by `sound:`

Comment: What I mean is that, the names of the files will be appended inside text, so if the name of one of the files is, say, "section_3_chapter_4_sentence_10.mp3", it will be appended into the cell surrounded by that the text, and inside the cell will be a string that looks like [sound:section_3_chapter_4_sentence_10.mp3]. So the idea is that libreoffice will loop through every single file in the directory and paste the name of every single file between that [sound:...] text and put every single one into the cells of a column.

Comment: Ah, square brackets and the word sound are constants? No problem! Collect the filenames into cells and format them with the format code `"[sound:"@"]"`. When exporting to CSV, do not forget to include the [Save cell content as shown option](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/00/00000207.html). However, if in fact you do not need an intermediate step "collect to Calc before export", then the macro can do everything necessary on its own.

Comment: You can do this very quickly without macros (and without "a for loop or something like that"). First, collect all the file names in a text file (in Windows this can be done with a command like `dir your_folder\*.mp3 /B >src.csv`). Then open the src.csv file in Calc, format column A as indicated in the previous comment, and save the result as a CSV file. When exporting, do not forget to uncheck [Quote all text cells](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/00/00000207.html) in order not to get extra quotes

Comment: I've been able to get all the filenames into cells, but I don't know what you mean by "format them with the format code". What do I need to do to get spreadsheets to append the [sound:"@"] around the text in each cell?

Comment: Step1 select all cells with filenames - go to A1 and press Ctrl+* (or Ctrl+Shift+End) Step2 Open Format Cells window - press Ctrl+1 or choose Format - Cells - Numbers tab. Step3 Type (or copy-paste from here) text `"[sound:"@"]"` to [Format Code](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/01/05020301.html) field and click OK. Step4 Press Ctrl+Shift+S or choose [File - Save As](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/01/01070000.html), select the file format **Text CSV** and check [Edit Filter Settings](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/00/00000207.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the system command to read the folder contents, as described in the comment to the question, then the following script will help you do the job:

```
Sub createFileList
Dim oFolderDialog As Object, oUcb As Object 
Dim sStartFolder As String 
Dim aList As Variant, aRes As Variant 
Dim nRow As Long, i As Long 
Dim sFullName As String, sFile As String
    Globalscope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("Tools")
    sStartFolder = ""
    oFolderDialog = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.FolderPicker")
    oUcb = createUnoService("com.sun.star.ucb.SimpleFileAccess")
    If oUcb.Exists(GetPathSettings("Work")) Then _
        oFolderDialog.SetDisplayDirectory(GetPathSettings("Work"))
    If oFolderDialog.Execute() = 1 Then
        sStartFolder = oFolderDialog.GetDirectory()
        If oUcb.Exists(sStartFolder) Then sStartFolder = ConvertFromUrl(sStartFolder)
    End If
    If sStartFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    aList = ReadDirectories(sStartFolder, False, False, False, , "mp3")
    nRow = UBound(aList)
    If nRow < 0 Then Exit Sub
    ReDim aRes(nRow)
    For i = LBound(aList) To UBound(aList)
        sFullName = ConvertFromURL(aList(i,0))
        sFile = FileNameOutOfPath(sFullName, GetPathSeparator())
        aRes(i) = "[sound:" & sFile & "]"
    Next i
    sFile = sStartFolder & GetPathSeparator() & "filelist.csv"
    sFile = InputBox("Specify the path and name for the output file:","Found " & (nRow + 1) & " files.", sFile)
    If sFile = "" Then Exit Sub
    SaveDataToFile(ConvertToURL(sFile),aRes)
End Sub
```